# how to call webapi at server startup in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have created a get web api that i want to hit at my server startup for some specific task. I have used this method

```
var request = require('request');
    request('http://localhost:3000/api/jobs/asd', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
      }
    }
```

)

But i am getting status code as 403. So i am not able to access my API at serve startup. Please suggest me the proper solution for the same.

thanks in adv.

Comment: Why  would your request to localhost print google web page ?

Comment: What happens when you open that url in your browser?

Comment: @JeremyM. its just my webapi url

Comment: @Archer it is hitting on my server but i want to hit at server startup

Comment: `403` status means you have to authenticate before you make the request.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed yup.. but i want to hit that API at my server startup. This is what my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code inside http callback like so :

```
http.createServer(app).listen(3000, () => {
    //your code here
});
```